# Ambiente Laravel com multi login

Tags: php, laravel

Tenho um projeto pessoal ao qual eu gostaria de disponibiliza-lo para algumas empresas, mas cada uma empresa deve ter seu próprio login, então a tela de login deveria ter o seguinte endereço: `www.projeto.com.br/empresa/login`.

Ou seja, o que eu quero é que no mesmo projeto, com o mesmo código, eu tenha um login que leve em consideração o endereço digitado para escolher em qual empresa o usuário está se logando. É possível fazer isso? Se sim, como eu resolveria as rotas?

Estou trabalhando com o `Laravel 5.4`, mas como ainda está em fase de definição, não tem nenhum código feito, a versão aqui é o menos importante.

Answer (score 0):

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'empresaTal', 'middleware' => 'auth'), function() { 

Route::get('login', array('as' => 'login.empresaTal', 'dashboard\AuthEmpresaTal@login'));

});
```

Acho que é isso que você precisa. Criar grupos de rotas

Comment: Route::get('login', array('as' => 'login.empresaTal','uses'. => 'dashboard\AuthEmpresaTal@login'));

Comment: Boa, eu estava tentando pelo autenticador do próprio Laravel, acho que o ideal é mesmo fazer um autenticador próprio. Valeu